# What is the "data.max" of a torch.Tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have been browsing the documentation of torch.Tensor, but I have not been able to find this (just similar things).

If `a_tensor` is a `torch.Tensor`, what is `a_tensor.data.max`? What type, etc.?

In particular, I am reading `a_tensor.data.max(1)[1]` and `a_tensor.data.max(1)[1][i].cpu().numpy()`.

Answer (score 3):

When accessing `.data` you are accessing the underlying data of the tensor. The returned object *is* a `Torch.*Tensor` as well, however, it won't be linked to any computational graph.

Take this example:

```
>>> x = torch.rand(4, requires_grad=True)
>>> y = x**2

>>> y
tensor([0.5272, 0.3162, 0.1374, 0.3004], grad_fn=<PowBackward0>)
```

While `y.data` is somewhat detached from graph (no `grad_fn` function), yet it is not a copy of `y` as `y.detach()` would return:

```
>>> y.data
tensor([0.5272, 0.3162, 0.1374, 0.3004]
```

Therefore, if you modify `y.data`'s components you end modifying `y` itself:

```
>>> y.data[0] = 1

>>> y
tensor([1.0000, 0.3162, 0.1374, 0.3004], grad_fn=<PowBackward0>)
```

Notice how the `grad_fn` didn't change there. If you had done `y[0] = 1`, `grad_fn` would have been updated to `<CopySlices>`. This shows that modify your tensor's data through `.data` is not accounted for in terms of gradient, *i.e.*, you won't be able to backpropagate these operations. It is required to work with `y` - *not `y.data`* - when planning to use Autograd.

---

So, to give an answer to your question: `a_tensor.data` is a `torch.*Tensor`, same type as `a_tensor`, and `a_tensor.data.max` is a function bound to that tensor.

Answer (score 0):

`a_Tensor.data` is of type `torch.Tensor` as well.

You can find the details related to `Tensor.max()` from [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.max.html).